# Positive integer solutions of $\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{2}{a_2}+\frac{3}{a_3}+\cdots+\frac{n}{a_n}=\frac{a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots+a_n}{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Find all ordered tuples of positive integers $(a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_n)$ such that
>   $\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{2}{a_2}+\frac{3}{a_3}+\cdots+\frac{n}{a_n}=\frac{a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots+a_n}{2}$

The only thing I have been able to think about is using inequalities. I have tried to apply AM-GM, Titu's lemma etc.. Cauchy-Schwarz gives the following thing:

$$(\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{2}{a_2}+\frac{3}{a_3}+\cdots+\frac{n}{a_n})(a_1+\cdots a_n) \ge (\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}+\cdots \sqrt{n})^2$$

$$(a_1+\cdots a_n)^2\ge 2(\sqrt{1}+\cdots \sqrt {n})^2$$

which doesn't really help us at all.

I have also tried considering smaller cases. For $n=2$,

$$a_1a_2(a_1+a_2)=4a_1+2a_2$$ which tells us that $2a_2=ka_1$ and $8a_1=pa_2=ka_1p\implies kp=8$. This should now give us all the solutions by checking all the cases.

So how can we even begin to attack this problem?

Comment: A remark: $a_i\mid 2i$ for each $i$ and note that solutions with $a_1 = 1$ are in bijective correspondence with solutions having $a_1 = 2$ just by taking the $n$-tuple with $2i/a_i$ in place of $a_i,$ so you can assume $a_1 = 1$ without loss of generality. Also, you can reduce it to an integer equation, but I don't know how helpful that is.

Comment: It should be $a_1 a_2 (a_1+a_2)=4a_1+2a_2$

Comment: There seems to be no solution for $n<4$, according to WolframAlpha.

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code Consider $a_n = \sqrt{2n}$ and it's easy to prove that this is solutions for all $n$ using induction.

Comment: @Stefan4024, why would $\sqrt{2n}$ be an integer for all $n$?

Comment: I missed the integer part. Anyway it's a solution when $a_n \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Stefan204, not related, but are there an infinite number of solutions over the reals? This looks like a question that deserves a question of its own(unless it is trivial and I am missing something).

Comment: For $n=3,$ there are two solutions: $(1,2,3)$ and $(2,2,2)$ so wolframalpha lied to you. @rah4927, yes, there are infinitely many solutions over the reals. Just pick $a_i \le i$ for $i < n$ and then by continuity you can always find $a_n$ that works.

Comment: What competition does this exercise come from?

Comment: @Vincenzo Oliva, this is actually a problem in one of Amir Hossein's number theory problem collection.

Comment: @rah4927 Oh I see, thanks.

Comment: @lyj Why should $a_i\mid 2i$?  You can easily arrange things to get cancellations even if the individual terms on the LHS aren't necessarily half-integers.

Comment: yes, you're right. my mistake!

Comment: @lyj, what made you think the original problem statement was wrong? Maybe that was the point of the question. I didn't even paraphrase the question from the source I cited. I copied it word for word.

Comment: @rah4927, I think you're right; my original line of thinking was that if they're all distinct, then the LHS is bounded by something smaller than the RHS, but I think I messed up. I'll revert it.

Comment: that being said, now it's unclear what the problem statement actually means, though we assume the more difficult one evidently

Comment: @vadim123, just asking for your opinion here, since you are the only answerer. Should the original version be brought back? Or should we stick with the "ordered tuples" question?

Comment: @rah4927, at this point you should probably leave it as modified, since it has spent most of its life this way.  You should also re-post the original version, and put in links from each question to the other.

Answer (score 5):

Partial solution:  If $n+1$ is a square, then set $a_1=a_2=\cdots=a_n=\sqrt{n+1}$.

Then the LHS is $$(1+2+\cdots+n)\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}=\frac{n(n+1)}{2\sqrt{n+1}}=\frac{1}{2}n\sqrt{n+1}$$

which agrees with the RHS.

---

More of a partial solution, following @Stefan4024's induction idea.  Start with a solution of the preceding form, then add two more terms to the LHS, namely $\frac{n+1}{b}+\frac{n+2}{b}$.  The equation will still balance if $$\frac{1}{b}(n+1+n+2)=\frac{b+b}{2}$$
or $b^2=2n+3$.  Hence, we seek $n$ satisfying (1) $n+1=a^2$; and (2) $2n+3=b^2$.  We can eliminate the $n$ to get [Pell's equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell's_equation):
$$b^2-2a^2=1$$
This has infinitely many solutions.  The smallest is $b=3, a=2$ ($n=3$, 5 terms).  The next smallest is $b=17, a=12$ ($n=143$, 145 terms).  The next one is $b=99, a=70$ ($n=4899$, 4901 terms).

Comment: I had found it but failed to prove it is the only solution besides $(1,2,3)$. Do you think this is the case?

Comment: Here's another: $(2,2,2,3,3)$.

Comment: Yeah. I liked how you improved your answer, +1.

Comment: @vadim123, someone edited the original problem to omit the condition that the $a_i$'s are distinct. Just thought I should let you know about the original problem.

Comment: Ack!  I saw the original version, too.  I suspect the solution is just $(1,2,3)$, since it's a contest problem.  The modified version may be too hard.

Comment: Ohoh, how could one prove that's the only solution?

Comment: If we multiply both sides with the product $a_1a_2…a_k...a_n$ we note that the $LHS=0$ (mod $a_k$) and that $k*a_1..a_{k-1} … a_{k+1}=0$ (mod  $a_k$), since all other LHS terms contain $a_k$ and is therefore $=0$ (mod  $a_k$)  ). If the $a_k$ are all different and < n  then $a_k=k$. One may perhaps develop this further but you can see that (1,2,3) is in line with this.

Comment: PS. I assumed that $a_k$ is not zero but I see this is not ruled out. Also I assume the terms $a_k$ are different.